# Xpath to find text by position 4th order td inside tbody and click edit in the same line

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-ide, browser-automation, katalon-recorder

Need help xpath to find text by position 4th order td inside tbody and click edit in the same line, example how to find base on ID Vegas123 inside td and click edit inside last td. Im usually use katalon-recorder for automate browser.

this is image example
https://ibb.co/G0VgXth

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question to include your code as text instead.